# How can I update my cart with Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, shopping-cart

I would really need some help from to AJAX Guru master overthere to help me building my update cart function on my website in AJAX.

So basically, what I would like to do is, when I modify one of my product in one input_dropdown, my 'update_cart' function is automaticaly called and my prices are updated as well as my input

EDIT : I rewrite my question since I made some progress thanks to Matei

Here is my view :

```
<?php 
          $options = array(
             '0'  => '0',
             '1'  => '1',
             '2'  => '2',
             '3'  => '3',
             '4'  => '4',
             '5'  => '5',
             '6'  => '6',
             '7'  => '7',
           );

       if($product['quantity']==0){
        $value[$product['title']] = set_value('quantity'.$product['title']);
       }else{
        $value[$product['title']] = $product['quantity'];
       }
       $data0 = 'class="quantSelect" value="'.$value[$product['title']].'" id="quant'.$product['title'].'"';

       echo  form_dropdown('quantity'.$product['title'], $options, $value[$product['title']],$data0);
     ?&gt;
    </td>
    <td>
     &lt;?php echo $product['price'] ?&gt;
    </td>
    <td id="&lt;?php echo 'price'.$product['title']?&gt;">
     $&lt;?php echo $total[$product['title']] ?&gt;
    </td>[/code]
```

Well, everything is in a foreach loop but I think that here, it doesn't matter.

Then I tried to set up the Matei AJAX function :

```
$(".quantSelect").click(function(){  
    $.POST("&lt;?php echo base_url().'main/update_cart';?&gt;",  
           {product_id:$('&lt;?php echo $product['quantity']; ?&gt;').val(),quantity:$('&lt;?php echo 'quantity'.$product['title'] ?&gt;').val()},  
           function(data){  
                if(data.success) {  
                     $("&lt;?php echo 'price'.$product['title']?&gt;").val(data.some_returned_value); // update value of an text input or textarea (view more info about jQuery selectors)
                     $("#totalPriceWithTaxes").html(data.some_other_returned_value); // update value of a paragraph                    
                }
           }, 'json');
});
```

And at last the update cart function :

```
function  update_cart(){
 $success = false;
  if(!empty($_POST['product_id']) && !empty($_POST['quantity']) && is_numeric($_POST['quantity'])) {  

   // I get all the information i need here in order to calcul the final price
   //We calcul the final price with taxes, shipping and everything.
   $data['totalPriceWithTaxes'] = $data['tax'] + $data['totalPrice'] + $data['Shipping']->shipping;
   $this->session->set_userdata('totalPriceWithTaxes', $data ['totalPriceWithTaxes']);

   $success = true;
   $some_returned_value = 69;
   $some_other_returned_value = $data['totalPriceWithTaxes']; // the final price
  }
 echo json_encode(array("success" => $success, 
      "some_returned_value" => $some_returned_value,
      "some_other_returned_value" => $some_other_returned_value));

 }
```

Here we are, so I can't see any update. If someone could help me to figure out how to set up that AJAX Function, I would deeply appreciate :)

Comment: I think you're asking far too many questions here.  Refactor your question to (like a good class) have one central purpose.

Comment: yeqh you re right, I rewrote that topic a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [jQuery.post() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) of jQuery library.

Let's see the following example:

Javascript code:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){  
    $.POST("/PATH_TO/update_cart.php",  
           {product_id:$('#product-id').val(),quantity:$('#quntity').val()},  
           function(data){  
                if(data.success) {  
                     $("#form-field-id").val(data.some_returned_value); // update value of an text input or textarea (view more info about jQuery selectors)
                     $("p#form-p-id").html(data.some_other_returned_value); // update value of a paragraph                    
                }
           }, 'json');
});
```

For more info about **jQuery Selectors** please [check this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

PHP code:

```
<?php
     $success = false;
     if(loged()) { // verify if the user is loged (if it's needed)
         if(!empty($_POST['product_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['product_id']) && !empty($_POST['quantity']) && is_numeric($_POST['quantity'])) {  
             // use here your additional code
             // update database
             // if every condition is applied then confirm that the fields are updated
             $success = true;
             $some_returned_value = "data has been successfully updated";
             $some_other_returned_value = 45.3; // the final price
         }
     }
     echo json_encode(array("success" => $success, 
                            "some_returned_value" => $some_returned_value,
                            "some_other_returned_value" => $some_other_returned_value));
?>
```

This is a simple example about how you can use jQuery POST method and PHP for updating data you want. I didn't use any of your code, but you can try to update your cart like this. jQuery is a powerfull library, so I'll recommend you to take a look at it.

Comment: thank you, so, I can use your first function to call my price() php function, ok, but how do I use Json ? do I have to simply fill that array and then write down '}, 'json');' at the end of the first function ?

Comment: you're right, json is a parameter for the $.POST method, so if you use it then you have to use the function json_encode() in the php file for returning the right type of data