# refresh the form without running through form validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm setting up a cart where the user can update the quantity. Because I don't know aJAX to do it instantly, I'm looking to do it in full php with a refresh cart. ( [you can still se my post where I try to set it up with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606079/how-can-i-update-my-cart-with-ajax))

The thing is that there is a form below the cart and when the user change the quantity (into an input) he has to click on 'refresh' or 'recalculate', whatever.

So my problem is I get the validation process running as the re-calculate is like a submit button ( the price is calculated at the begining of the form method) because the user modified an input, and for all the fields that has not been filled yet, I got an error.

How can I say "If the user click on refresh, don't submit the form to the validation process, just take that input in consideration" ? I don't know if it is possible to have 2 separated forms on the same page ? (they are inside each other)

By the Way, I'm using codeIgniter.

I give a part of my form, I need  to listen to the

`form_dropdown('quantity'.$product['title'],$options,$value[$product['title']],$data0);`

when I want to update the quantity, and only this one.

```
<ul class="form">
    <li>
        <h2>Your Information</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="form" id="threeColumns">
            <li>
                <?php
                echo form_open('main/Form');

                echo form_label('First Name', 'firstname');
                echo ' :</br>';
                if (set_value('firstname')) {
                    $valuefirstname = set_value('firstname');
                } else {
                    $valuefirstname = $this->session->userdata('firstname');
                }
                echo form_input('firstname', $valuefirstname);
                echo form_error('firstname');

                echo '</li><li>';

                echo form_label('Last Name', 'lastname');
                echo ' :</br>';
                if (set_value('firstname')) {
                    $valuelastname = set_value('lastname');
                } else {
                    $valuelastname = $this->session->userdata('lastname');
                }
                echo form_input('lastname', $valuelastname);
                echo form_error('lastname');

                echo '</li><li>';

                echo form_label('Email', 'email');
                echo ' :</br>';
                if (set_value('firstname')) {
                    $valueemail = set_value('email');
                } else {
                    $valueemail = $this->session->userdata('email');
                }
                echo form_input('email', $valueemail);
                echo form_error('email');
                ?>
                <div class="fError Right">
                    <?php
                    if (ISSET($error) AND $error != NULL)
                        echo $error;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <div class="break">
    </div>

    <li id="Payment">
        <div id='Table'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th id="top-left">
                        Product
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Color
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Quantity
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price Per Product
                    </th>
                    <th id= "top-right">
                        Total
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                    <tr class="line">
                        <td>
                            <img id="tableImage" src="<?php echo base_url($product['image_url']) ?>" alt="product" width="121"  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $product['title'] ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            $options = array(
                                '0' => '0',
                                '1' => '1',
                                '2' => '2',
                                '3' => '3',
                                '4' => '4',
                                '5' => '5',
                                '6' => '6',
                                '7' => '7',
                            );

                            if ($product['quantity'] == 0) {
                                $value[$product['title']] = set_value('quantity' . $product['title']);
                            } else {
                                $value[$product['title']] = $product['quantity'];
                            }
                            $data0 = 'class="quantSelect" value="' . $value[$product['title']] . '" id="quant' . $product['title'] . '"';

                            echo form_dropdown('quantity' . $product['title'], $options, $value[$product['title']], $data0);
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $product['price'] ?>
                        </td>
                        <td id="<?php echo 'price' . $product['title'] ?>">
                            $<?php echo $total[$product['title']] ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to have two rulesets for your form. One is with all the fields and 'required'. The other is the same rules, but no 'required'

Then if refresh, run form validation with no 'required'

If submit, run form validation with the required ruleset.